# Continuity of $f:[0,1)\to S^1$ defined by, $f(t)=(\cos 2πt,\sin 2πt)$ where $S^1 = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb {R}^2| x^2+y^2=1\}$

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I'm studying homeomorphism between topological spaces.
The above function is a example of bijective function but not a homeomorphism.

I'm able to see that it's a bijective function and $f^{-1}$  is not continues.

Here $f^{-1}$ is not continuous since if we take $U=[0,\frac{1}{4}) $ then $f^{-1}(U)$ is not open in $S^1$, because $f(0)$ lies in no basis element $V=(a,b)\times(c,d)$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $(V\cap S^1)\subset f(U)$

But The book says that $f$ is continus, which I'm not able to show.

Can anyone give some light how to prove $f$ is continuous.
Thank you.

Comment: $[0,\frac 14)$ is not a subset of $S^1$, so $f^{-1}(U)$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: @aschepler here $U$ is open set in the codomain of inverse function $f^{-1}$ which is $[0,1)$.

Comment: @aschepler, I assume OP wants to show that $f^{-1}$ is not continuous, so it should be $f(U)$ instead (since $f$ is bijective).

Comment: Nimu, open sets of $S^1$ come from relative topology, so take open ball in $\mathbb R^2$. What can intersection of that be with $S^1$?

Comment: Right, $f^{-1}$ is continuous if $f(U)$ is open for every open $U \subseteq [0,1)$ (since $(f^{-1})^{-1} = f$). The key issue here is what is an open subset of $[0,1)$....

Comment: @Ennar thank you for suggesting.The intersection will be a arc section of $S^1$ or union of two arc section of $S^1$. But then how then how I get the pre- image set of this arc section mathematically.

Comment: Do you know that image of an interval $(a,b)$ under $f$ is an arc? From bijectivity it follows that preimage of an arc is an interval, then.

Comment: @Ennar The preimage of the arc $S^1 \cap \{(x,y) \mid x>0\}$ is $[0,1/4) \cup (3/4,1)$...

Comment: @aschepler, ah, yes, you are right, but you can deal separately with the case when $(1,0)$ is in the arc and when it is not. What I wrote applies when $(1,0)$ is not on the arc. When it is, split that arc into two so that you get union of open sets in $[0,1)$ as in your example.

Comment: Or, you can take the complement of the arc that contains $(0,1)$ to get a closed interval in $[0,1)$. In your example, @aschepler, preimage of $S^1\cap \{(x,y)\mid x\leq 0\}$ is $[1/4,3/4]$, so it's complement in $[0,1)$ is open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider inclusion map $i\colon S^1\hookrightarrow \mathbb R^2$ given by $(x,y)\mapsto (x,y)$. For any open set $U$ of $\mathbb R^2$, we have $i^{-1}(U) = S^1 \cap U$, so open sets of $S^1$ are precisely those of the form $i^{-1}(U)$ for $U\subseteq \mathbb R^2$ open. *(Said in different way, relative topology is the smallest topology such that inclusion map is continuous).*

Consider maps $f_1,f_2\colon [0,1) \to \mathbb R$ given by formulas $f_1(t) = \cos(2\pi t)$, $f_2(t) = \sin(2\pi t)$. Since they are both continous, by the universal property of product, map $\tilde f\colon [0,1)\to \mathbb R^2$ given by formula $\tilde f(t) = (f_1(t), f_2(t))$ is continuous. Note that map $\tilde f$ factors through $S^1$, i.e. $\tilde f = i\circ f$. By continuity of $\tilde f$, we have that for any open $U$ in $\mathbb R^2$ $$\tilde f^{-1}(U) = (i\circ f)^{-1}(U) = f^{-1}(i^{-1}(U))$$ is open in $[0,1)$. But, this proves that $f\colon [0,1) \to S^1$ is continuous since all open sets of $S^1$ are of the form $i^{-1}(U)$.

Comment: Excellent explanation!!!